# Why is TimeSpan constructed with 100ns "ticks"?

Tags: .net, timespan

The TimeSpan class can be constructed with days, hours, minutes, seconds and milliseconds:

```
public TimeSpan(int hours, int minutes, int seconds);
public TimeSpan(int days, int hours, int minutes, int seconds);
public TimeSpan(int days, int hours, int minutes, int seconds, int milliseconds);
```

It can also be constructed with "ticks" which are 100 nanosecond units of time:

```
public TimeSpan(long ticks);
```

What is the significance of 100 nanoseconds when a lot of other time-related objects (eg. System.Timers.Timer.Interval) are based on millisecond units?  Also, why not use microseconds, which are 10x longer, but a much more common unit of time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because Wintel computers are based on a hardware clock that uses 100ns ticks.

Comment: hard to resist to ask why again here ;)

Answer (score 3):

It is not easy to answer "why" questions unless you were involved in the decision making yourself. That being said the 100 ns tick could very well be an inspiration from VMS as indicated by HABO's answer ([Dave Cutler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dave_Cutler) was involved in the design of both VMS and Windows NT).

However, with the constraint that you want to fit a time span into a signed 64 bit number it makes sense to use 100 ns as the tick value. The largest time span (`TimeSpan.MaxValue`) is

```
0x7FFF FFFF FFFF FFFF ticks
  = 9 223 372 036 854 775 807 ticks
  = 9 223 372 036 854 775 807 ticks / 10 000 000 ticks/s
  = 922 337 203 685 s
  ~ 30 000 years
```

Different ticks values results in different maximum time spans:

```
Ticks  | Max time span (approx.)
-------+------------------------
 10 ns |   3 000 years
100 ns |  30 000 years
  1 μs | 300 000 years
```

Ignoring `DateTime.Kind` a `DateTime` value is basically a `TimeSpan` offset from the epoch 01-01-0001 00:00:00 (`DateTime.MinValue`) so with 100 ns ticks you can accommodate the date 31-12-9999 23:59:59 (`DateTime.MaxValue`). That would not be possible with a 10 ns ticks where you would run out of ticks before year 3000. And with 1 μs ticks you lower the time resolution by a factor 10 without getting anything in return with respect to representation of dates assuming year 10000 is the first year "you don't care about".

With that in mind it seems that using a signed 64 bit value the smallest tick value that still will allow you to represent all 4 digit years is 100 ns.

(And if you believed the year 2000 problem was hard on the IT industry just wait for the year 10000 problem.)

Answer (score 2):

It is a [clunk](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenVMS#Timekeeping), a unit of time used in [Open]VMS.

Comment: Looks like it's been around for awhile.

Comment: ... interesting references there: [README file for clunk routine](http://www.ibiblio.org/pub/academic/computer-science/history/pdp-11/rsx/decus/rsx89b/374101/readme.clu) (Feb 1981) and [THE WOMBAT EXAMINER](http://www.bighole.nl/pub/mirror/mini-me.trailing-edge.com/pub/rsx11freewarev2/rsx86b/356030/wevol3n1.prt) (Nov 1987)

Comment: @Wolf VMS also used [microfortnights](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FFF_system#Microfortnight_and_other_decimal_prefixes) as an approximation for seconds during booting. (And I still have my Datatrieve Wombat magnet on my filing cabinet.)

Comment: [WOW](http://catb.org/jargon/html/A/attoparsec.html)! *1 attoparsec/microfortnight equals about 1 inch/sec* :-)